# Difference between interpolation (using {} squiggly brackets) and concatenation (., or dot) when constructing an SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What´s the difference between:

```
$sql = "select * from {$table}";
```

and this:

```
$sql = "select * from ".$table;
```

Are there any differences?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: The difference is that you shall not use the former.

Comment: One side note: if `$table` contains user input, don't forget to use a proper escaping function and put single quotes around the variable to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't much of a difference other than one uses concatenation and one doesn't.

You can also write it as

```
$sql = "select * from $table";
```

You can use `{}` in your string to refer to objects as well.

If table were a name or array

```
$sql = "select * from {$table->name}"; //works
$sql = "select * from $table->name"; //works too
$sql = "select * from $table->innerTable->table"; //doesn't work

$sql = "select * from {$table['name']}"; //works
$sql = "select * from $table['name']"; //breaks
```

I personally use it to increase readability, because I'll always know I'm referring to a variable.

Comment: $table->data->name would break, but $table->name works. and technically @nikic, example4 is correct, tho, didnt know if u dropped the quotes it worked, so +1 for u

Comment: @nikic I know the example works if you drop the quotes. Which is why they are included. It's not a typo. Quoted and unquoted indices inside a string are different. You're correct about example 2. Fixing it now, thanks

Comment: @Ascherer yup, one reference is ok, more than one and it breaks. Updated, thanks

Answer (score 7):

The outcome will be the same, but of course you do two fundamental different things:

The first one is [**variable parsing**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) (which only works in double quoted and *heredoc* strings), the second one is [**string concatenation**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Answer (score 4):

No - both will evaluate within PHP to the same string.

So will

```
$sql = "select * from $table";
```

Comment: In this case both are equivalent, but in general they aren’t.

Answer (score 1):

you even can do this in php: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ";` it's just an alias.

Comment: kind of :-) ... i am no native speaker ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned both statements result in the same string being assigned to $sql. Note though that using single quotes and concatenation is slightly more efficient since the string do not need to be parsed by the PHP interpreter:

```
$sql = 'select * from ' . $table;
```